# Rotate image with open office 3.2

Tags: images, openoffice, processing, rotate

I import a picture into an open office document from file.
However, I cannot figure out how to rotate image in open office 3.2 writer.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No easy way. You can open the image in OpenOffice Draw, and use the Mode toolbar to free rotate the image. Then copy it and paste it back into OpenOffice Write. Or, you could select Insert -> Object -> OLE Object... Then create a new OpenOffice Drawing, paste your image into that drawing, and use the Mode toolbar to rotate it.

Comment: Oh. I've just scanned through an issue of OO Writer saying that it will not deliver this feature until version 3.5. Well...

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it looks like Draw as an intermediate step is the best way.
I pasted as GDI metafile into a temporary Draw file, which gives access to the key "Position and Size" menu item.  My source file is a MS Powerpoint file.  I also tried pasting as Microsoft Power Point Slide but "Position and Size" is greyed out and unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to Rotate an Image in Open Office Writer

1. First of all open “Open Office Drawing”
2. Goto Insert menu and Select “Picture”>>”From File”
3. Insert the image on it
4. now you will see the image's borders looking in green dots.
5. Please select any one corner of the green dot and you will see the green dots changing to red dots.
6. Move the mouse on any red dot to see the 'rotate' symbol being activated.
7. Now don't do any thing to the image.
8. Next Open “Open Office Writer”
9. Copy the image from “Open Office Drawing” to “Open Office Writer”
10. Goto 'View' dropdown menu and select 'tool bars' >>'Drawing object properties'
11. There you will see a 'slanting G' (or a  reverse circle arrow mark) like logo which is the 'rotation tool' called “ROTATE”.
12. select it and go to any corner of the image and click it to see it becoming Red again (In fact, all the borders of the image becomes Red).
13. Now the image is completely ready for rotation as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux, an easy way is to use convert before including the picture:

```
convert pic.jpg -rotate 90 rotated_pic.jpg
```

Comment: bad answer. not related to open office at all. not related to windows or mac also.